# How to use jquery UI in Drupal?

Tags: jquery, drupal, jquery-ui

I've just installed jquery-ui-module, but don't know how to use it. Can someone help me please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If 1000 views mean something, isn't it time to reconsider to reopen this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery UI library provides some of the ready made common UI effects and functionalities like `accordion, draggable tables, sortable tables, progress bar, date-pickers` and so on. jquery_ui is a module that ports the jquery UI library to Drupal that's all.

In general other modules would depend on this module to provide some jquery functionalities. Anyway if you are writing a custom module of your own, you can use the snippets from Jquery UI library if you have enabled this module.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you installed this module: http://drupal.org/project/jquery_ui

Whatever, you should read JQueryUI documentation. It's very well explained with a lot of examples: http://jqueryui.com/demos/

It's really hard to explain every single module one by one. Just try to learn from examples. Happy codding!

Comment: I just want to know how I can use it that's it, and what I can do with this module?

Comment: @Tassisto For example http://blog.houen.net/drupal-jquery-ui-complete-guide/ (read point #11). You can do display a lot of stuff dynamically, with a few very well designed effects.